# How to delete files saved on the server after sending and email with SMTP client in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, smtpclient

I have a project on M.V.C 4 C# internet application and i have followed some guides to save Google visualization column chart to an image to my drive with ajax function.Also i am making a P.D.F format report with razor P.D.F nugget package.The path is: "C\temp\" and both files are there.I need to attach both files to an email and send them and then to delete the created files.

I call the send email function with ajax :

```
$('#btnSend').on('click', function () {
            if (from) {
                fromDate = from.toJSON();
            }

            if (to) {
                toDate = to.toJSON();
            }
            // from and to are dates taken from two datepickers

            // saves the pdf to the server
            if (from && to) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/SavePdf/",
                    data: { fromDate: fromDate, toDate: toDate },
                    type: 'GET',
                    async: false,
                    datatype: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert('got here with data');
                    },
                    error: function () { alert('something bad happened'); }
                });
            }


            // saves the column chart to the server from canvas item with id reports

            var imgData = getImgData(document.getElementById("reports"));
            var imageData = imgData.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/SaveImage/",
                type: 'POST',
                data: '{ "imageData" : "' + imageData + '" }',
                datatype: 'json',
                async: false,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function () {
                    alert('Image saved successfully !');
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('something bad happened');
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/SendMail/",
                async: false,
                success: function() {
                    alert('Message sent successfully');
                }
            });
        });
```

and here is my function in the code behind

```
public void SendMail()
        {
            var path = @"C:\temp\";
            string pngFilePath = path + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".png";
            string pdfFilePath = path + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".pdf";

            MailMessage message = new MailMessage("message sender", "message reciever")
            {
                Subject = "Test",
                Body = @"Test"
            };
            Attachment data = new Attachment(pdfFilePath , 

 MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
        message.Attachments.Add(data);

        Attachment data2 = new Attachment(pngFilePath , GetMimeType(pngFilePath); 
 // GetMimeType function gets the mimeType of the unknown attachment
        message.Attachments.Add(data2);

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Host = "smtp.googlemail.com";
        client.Port = 587;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mail sender", "sender password");
        client.Send(message);

        // delete the png after message is sent
        if ((System.IO.File.GetAttributes(pngFilePath ) & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly) 
        {

            System.IO.File.SetAttributes(pngFilePath , FileAttributes.Normal);            

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(pngFilePath ))  
            {     
                System.IO.File.Delete(pngFilePath ); 
            }  
        }

        // delete the pdf after message is sent
        if ((System.IO.File.GetAttributes(pdfFilePath ) & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
        {

            System.IO.File.SetAttributes(pdfFilePath , FileAttributes.Normal);

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(pdfFilePath ))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(pdfFilePath );
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to delete those files, but IIS continues to use them and delete operation is never reached. Is there any way to disattach those files from iis and delete them ?

Comment: What about if you Dispose de SmtpClient before deleting the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `SmtpClient` that locks the files. Create a stream for each file and use that as an attachment.
Something like this:

```
using(Stream fs1 = File.OpenRead(pdfFilePath))
using(Stream fs2 = File.OpenRead(pngFilePath))
{
   Attachment data = new Attachment(fs1 , GetMimeType(pdfFilePath));
   Attachment data2 = new Attachment(fs2 , GetMimeType(pngFilePath));
   message.Attachments.Add(data);
   message.Attachments.Add(data2);
   ...
   client.Send(message);
}
```

EDIT: My initial suggestion, to use `client.Dispose()` after sending the mail, doesn't seem to work

Comment: Only client.Dispose() is not working, but disposing the client inside structure like you suggested -> using streams for both files, does the trick ;] thanks

Comment: @dlght Glad to help. Consider changing the title of your question and replace "still in use of the IIS" with something like "after sending email" to be more specific about the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

I add the same problem and I saw previous answer.

It is possible to use `client.Dispose()` but you alse have to do `message.Attachments.Dispose()`.

After that you can delete your file.